# Multithreaded Python Program faster than Single Threaded program for CPU bound task

Tags: python, multithreading

EDIT : Turns out this weird behavior was happening only with python in my WSL ubuntu. Otherwise, sequential does run faster than multi-threaded one.

I understand that, for CPython, in general, multiple-threads just context-switch while utilizing the same CPU-core and not utilize multiple CPU-cores like with multi-processing where several instances of python interpreter gets started.

I know this makes multithreading good for I/O bound tasks if done right. Nevertheless, CPU bound tasks will actually be slower with multi-threading. So, I experimented with 3 code snippets each doing some CPU bound calculations.

- Example 1 : Runs tasks in sequence (single thread)
- Example 2 : Runs each task in different thread (Multithreaded)
- Example 3 : Runs each task in separate processes (Multi-processed)

To my surprise, even though task is CPU bound, Example 2 utilizing multiple threads  is executing faster (on avg 1.5 secs) than Example 1 using single thread (on avg 2.2 secs). But Example 3 runs the fastest as expected (on avg 1 sec).

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

## Example 1 : Run tasks Sequentially

```
import time 
import math

nums = [ 8, 7, 8, 5, 8]

def some_computation(n):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(int(math.pow(n,n))):
        counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    for i in nums:
        some_computation(i)
    end = time.time()
    print("Total time of program execution : ", round(end-start, 4) )
```

## Example 2 : Run tasks with Multithreading

```
import threading
import time 
import math

nums = [ 8, 7, 8, 5, 8]
def some_computation(n):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(int(math.pow(n,n))):
        counter += 1
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    threads = []
    for i in nums: 
        x = threading.Thread(target=some_computation, args=(i,))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    end = time.time()
    print("Total time of program execution : ", round(end-start, 4) )
```

## Example 3 : Run tasks in parallel with `multiprocessing` module

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import math

nums = [ 8, 7, 8, 5, 8]
def some_computation(n):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(int(math.pow(n,n))):
        counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=3)
    for i in nums:
        pool.apply_async(some_computation, [i])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    end = time.time()
    print("Total time of program execution : ", round(end-start, 4) )
```

Comment: "Example 2 utilizing multiple threads is executing faster (on avg 2.2 secs) than Example 1 using single thread (on avg 1.5 secs)" Sounds like example 1 is faster no?

Comment: During some operations and calls to external libraries the global interpreter lock is released. Therefore e. g. the actual "math.pow" calculation may be able to run in parallel to some other Python code or another "math.pow" calculation.

Comment: The general principle that CPU bound processes should be run discretely (as processes) rather than as threads is entirely correct. However, it can depend on exactly what those threads/processes are doing. In this case, for example, there's a call into the math module (which is actually unnecessary because you could write *n\*\*n* which is faster). Stick to multiprocessing for things like this. Also, use time.perf_counter() for timing

Comment: @flakes Thanks for mentioning that typo. Fixed it. But still, original question that Multithreaded program is executing faster in this case, remains valid.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't think that's the case. I swapped out "math.pow" with my own logic to calculate the power. Result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was happening only in ubuntu that I had installed in Windows Subsystem for Linux. My original snippets runs as expected in Windows or Ubuntu python environment but not in WSL i.e Sequential Execution running faster than Multithreaded one. Thanks @Vlad to double check things on your end.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, it's a question of what the function is actually doing.

If we make the *nums* list longer (i.e., there will be more concurrent threads/processes) and also adjust the way the loop range is calculated then we see this:

```
import time 
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor

nums = [8,7,8,5,8,8,5,4,8,7,7,8,8,7,8,8,8]

def some_computation(n):
    counter = 0
    for _ in range(n*1_000_000):
        counter += 1
    return counter

def sequential():
    for n in nums:
        some_computation(n)

def threaded():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(some_computation, nums)

def pooled():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(some_computation, nums)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for func in sequential, threaded, pooled:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        func()
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(func.__name__, f'{end-start:.4f}')
```

**Output:**

```
sequential 4.8998
threaded 5.1257
pooled 0.7760
```

This indicates that the complexity of *some_computation()* determines how the system is going to behave. With this code and its adjusted parameters we see that threading is slower than running sequentially (as one would typically expect) and, of course, multiprocessing is significantly faster

Comment: I found the answer. Even for your example, sequential was running slower. Then I realized I was using ubuntu from Windows Subsystem for Linux. So fired up my ubuntu and tested my original code. then the sequential was actually faster than threaded one.  But thanks for the double check ! :)

Comment: @badprogrammer When testing code for performance it's important to think about where it's going to be deployed. Different operating systems, variations in Python version and (more importantly) hardware is likely to give different results. It would be very interesting to know what figures you get with the **exact** code in my answer

Comment: For ubuntu in my WSL : sequential-> 4.9, threaded-> 4.2, pooled->1.44,
On my ubuntu Machine : sequential-> 4.5, threaded -> 6, pooled-> 1

Comment: @badprogrammer Very interesting and proof positive that the same code on different platforms can perform quite differently. FYI -> iMac Pro running macOS 12.5.1 on 3 GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W and Python 3.10.6 for my tests